# Why is my program looking for "desktop.bmp"?

Tags: c++, path

I am working on a program where I iterate through a folder that contains roughly 500 images of .bmp format. The images are named using random letters and numbers (example "151t12_4.bmp"). I am using OpenCV using C++ in Visual Studio 2022 to make changes to the images (opening, closing, contours, dilation, etc.)
I am saving the results of the image characteristics (length, width, black pixels, etc.) in a CSV file. Everything is working fine except the fact that the program tries reading "desktop.bmp" in the folder even though it does not exist.

It always stops running the program because it cannot find the file (obviously), so I renamed a file to desktop.bmp and it worked fine. **What's the reason for such an unusual behaviour and how to fix it?** I tried using another image folder, but it returned the same error.

Another problem I noticed is that the program saves 2 entries for "desktop.bmp" in the CSV file that I am creating. Now, it is not a problem per se, but I would like to know what is causing this and how to fix it?

Here's how my code looks like:

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/types.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgcodecs.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <filesystem> 

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;
using directory_iterator = filesystem::directory_iterator;
namespace fs = filesystem;
string get_stem(const fs::path& p) { return p.stem().string(); }

int main()
{
    fstream image_details;
    fstream file1("image_details.csv");
    if (!file1.is_open()) {
        image_details.open("image_details.csv", ios::out);
        image_details << "Image Name, Width, Height \n";
    }

    else
        image_details.open("image_details.csv", ios::app);


    string img_path = "C:\\Users\\TheHiredGoon\\Desktop\\image_folder"

    for (const auto& dirEntry : directory_iterator(img_path))
    {
        string img_name, path = get_stem(dirEntry);
        img_name = path;
        path = img_path + "\\" + img_name + ".bmp";

        Mat src = imread(path);
        Mat src_grey = imread(path, IMREAD_GRAYSCALE);

        Mat thresh;
        threshold(src_grey, thresh, 0, 255, THRESH_OTSU | THRESH_BINARY);
        vector<vector<Point>> contours;
        vector<Vec4i> hierarchy;
        findContours(thresh, contours, hierarchy, RETR_TREE, CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

        //sorting the contours by size (descending order)
        sort(contours.begin(), contours.end(), [](const vector<Point>& c1, const vector<Point>& c2)
            {
                return contourArea(c1, false) > contourArea(c2, false);
            });

        for (int x = 0; x < contours.size(); x++) {
            cout << "Size of contour " << x << " = " << contours[x].size() << endl;
        }

        vector<vector<Point> > contours_poly(contours.size());
        vector<Rect> boundRect(contours.size());
        int area[20] = {}, perimeter[20] = {};
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            approxPolyDP(contours[i], contours_poly[i], 3, true);
            boundRect[i] = boundingRect(contours_poly[i]);
            area[i] = contourArea(contours_poly[i]);
            perimeter[i] = arcLength(contours_poly[i], true);
        }

        Mat drawing = src_grey.clone();
        for (size_t i = 0; i < contours.size(); i++)
        {
            rectangle(drawing, boundRect[i].tl(), boundRect[i].br(), Scalar(0, 255, 0), 2);
        }

        Mat img_crop;
        img_crop = drawing(boundRect[1]);
        // the compiler indicates that the above line is the "Next statement to execute when this thread returns from the current function"

        Mat open_img, closed_img;
        int morph_size = 2;

        // Create structuring element
        Mat element = getStructuringElement(MORPH_RECT, Size(2 * morph_size + 1, 2 * morph_size + 1), Point(morph_size, morph_size));

        morphologyEx(binary_image, closed_img, MORPH_CLOSE, element, Point(-1, -1), 1);
        morphologyEx(closed_img, open_img, MORPH_OPEN, element, Point(-1, -1), 1);

        open_img.convertTo(open_img, CV_32FC1);

        // For Erosion
        erode(open_img, open_img, element, Point(-1, -1), 1);
       
        // For Dilation
        dilate(open_img, open_img, element, Point(-1, -1), 1);

        //Yes, the same image was eroded and dilated.

        image_details << img_name << "," << src.cols << "," << src.rows << "\n";
    }

    image_details.close();

    return 0;
}
```

The code works for all the files in folder and is giving expected results but it looks for a file "desktop.bmp" in the directory, which ideally it shouldn't. Here's a snippet of the error I am facing.
[The output dialog box](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zTHtJ.png) and the [output at the terminal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCS4n.png).

On pressing "Retry", these are the places where it points to

1. [vector file in the 'include' folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/plAKO.png)
2. ```
   Mat img_crop;
   img_crop = drawing(boundRect[1]);
   ```

   of the original code (also added as comments in the above code).

P.S.: My OpenCV directory is directly saved in C: while the code and the image folder are saved on Desktop. The `for` loop that I am using looks like this `for (const auto& dirEntry : directory_iterator(image_folder))`. I am using C++ 20

Comment: How much help do you expect people to be able to give if you don't post any of the actual code that's doing this?

Comment: Why would the *compiler* need an image? It would not, unless you misconfigured the build-system to attempt to build with this file. Are you sure it's the *compiler* that asks for it and not your own program? What is the actual error you get? If it's a real build-error then copy-paste (as text!) the full and complete build log into your question. Together with all information possibly about your build setup and system. Please [edit] your question to improve it.

Comment: Ah yes the well known `desktop.bmp` bug that affects Microsoft's implementation of the filesystem library prior to v11.4. Update your runtime. Obviously the previous is a not very funny joke, but your question cannot be answered any other way. Either you're going to hit the jackpot with some easily recognisable bug, or, much more likely, your question is going to be unanswerable. If you want help with code you need to post the code. I find it amazing that some posters to this site don't appreciate this.

Comment: I am sorry, I didn't know the rules of posting a question here. I should've read them before, my mistake. I have edited my question to provide more context. Thank you for your patience!

Comment: You'll be finding the hidden `desktop.ini` file, as you don't check the extension and change the extension to .bmp you'll encounter this problem

Comment: IIRC there is a way of telling Windows not to produce those `desktop.ini` files. Or at the very least not hiding them when they are there.

Comment: I couldn't find any `desktop.ini` files in the image folder or the folder where my program is saved. I searched for updates but my VS 22 says it is up to date. Am I missng something? I installed my VS 22 only a month ago. I am new to the language here, so I need more details (in simpler terms). Thanks for the support though!

Comment: The point of *hidden* files is that you should not see them. The `desktop.ini` file is unrelated to your development environment (VS22) or your program, it's a general Windows thing. The simple workaround is to simply skip over that file in your loop: `if (dirEntry == "desktop.ini"){ continue; }`

Comment: So, do I have to keep this in mind each time I am working on a code which involves folders on Desktop or is it unique to this program? Is there any permanent fix for this bug? Also, any idea why is it searching for `desktop.ini` or `desktop.bmp` twice?

Comment: No, Windows adds desktop.ini as configuration file how the windows explorer should show the contents of that directory. Your code replaces .ini with .bmp (for unknown to us reasons) also your code calls imread() twice for it (for unknown to us reasons) so do not ask us "why". You should ask that question from yourself.

Comment: simply just debugging the code, i.e. single-stepping through it, or printing some variables as it executes, should have revealed the issue. I can't understand how such a question gained five upvotes, in such a short time too!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
for (const auto& dirEntry : directory_iterator(img_path))
{
    string img_name, path = get_stem(dirEntry);
    img_name = path;
    path = img_path + "\\" + img_name + ".bmp";
```

You discard the extension of the file. You then add `.bmp` as the extension. If there is a file in the directory which isn't a `.bmp` file (e.g. in this case the hidden `desktop.ini` file) then you'll change the extension of the filename to `.bmp` and try to open it, this will obviously fail (unless there happens to be a `.bmp` with the same name).

You should check the extension of each file in your code before proceeding. you should also check that the entry is actually a file, not a directory. I'm not sure why you're doing `string img_name, path = get_stem(dirEntry); img_name = path;` rather than just `string img_name = get_stem(dirEntry);`?

Fixing these gives:

```
std::filesystem::path img_path = "C:\\Users\\TheHiredGoon\\Desktop\\image_folder"
for (const auto& dirEntry : directory_iterator(img_path))
{
    if (!dirEntry.is_regular_file() || dirEntry.path().extension() != ".bmp")
    {
        continue;
    }
    string img_name = get_stem(dirEntry);
    auto path = img_path / dirEntry.path();
```

Note that this will only accept `.bmp` not `.Bmp` or `.BMP`, if you want to fix that you can convert the extension to lower case or use [`boost::iequals`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/iequals.html).

Comment: This code worked, thank you for your help. Is it necessary to include this `if` condition each time I am working with images (jpg, png, etc) on a desktop folder? I understand that the `dirEntry.is_regular_file()` seems to be a good practice for keeping the code away from unusual runtime behaviours.

Comment: @TheHiredGoon If you only want to work with certain file extensions then yes, you need to check that the file extension matches your expectation. `directory_iterator` returns all files in a folder, it doesn't know that you're only expecting images

Comment: @TheHiredGoon In general you should program more defensively, you don't check that `imread` succeeds, you don't check that `boundRect` contains at least 2 elements before calling `boundRect[1]`. The more problems you anticipate and check for the less debugging you'll have to do when your program crashes unexpectedly (hopefully it won't crash at all, it'll just show a meaningful error message)